# Select specific records in grid view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I can't get the text.contains("9999999") statement to return true. The column with index of 1 has ID#'s. These id's are anchor tagged and I need to remove the tags if the id number is 9999999. Everything else in the main if statement works correctly.

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        lDate = e.Row.Cells(8).Text
        e.Row.Cells(7).Text = ConvertDate(e.Row.Cells(7).Text, True)
        e.Row.Cells(8).Text = ConvertDate(e.Row.Cells(8).Text, True)

        If e.Row.Cells(1).Text.Contains("9999999") = True Then
            Regex.Replace(e.Row.Cells(1).Text, "</?(a|A).*?>", "")
            Dim yoasd As String = e.Row.Cells(1).Text
        End If

        If e.Row.Cells(8).Text.Trim = "" Or lDate < lToday Then
            e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.BurlyWood
        End If
    End If
```

I've also tried:

```
If e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "9999999"
If e.Row.Cells(1).Text.Trim = "9999999"
If e.Row.Cells(1).Text.Contains("9999999") Then
```

Comment: Please output msgbox(e.Row.Cells(1).Text) and msgbox (e.Row.Cells(1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this on your RowDataBound

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
dim toberemoved as string = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ColumName")
if toberemoved = "9999999" then
Regex.Replace(e.Row.Cells(1).Text, "</?(a|A).*?>", "")
//Morestuff here
End If
End If
```

Remember to replace ColumName with the actuall name of the colum

*not tested built from memory.

Comment: Thanks! Now I just have to figure out why my regex isn't working.